# how to modify the list of currently injected dependencies in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I 'm trying to create a modular angular app with capability to insert new modules in the back-end panel or remove currently added ones.

1. how can I get the list of currently added dependencies in the
   angular app ?
2. how can I modify them ? (insert, remove).

Comment: To load a dependency you could use http://api.jquery.com/load/ , it is intially designed for html loading but it can work for JS loading too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of module dependencies are in `requires` property of module.

E.g.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["dep1"]);
console.log(app.requires);
```

You can try to add a dependency to this list in run time. This simple example worked for me.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    var app1 = angular.module("ag.test", []);
    app1.factory("agTestFactory", [function() {
        return {
            hello: function() {
                console.log("hello");
            }
        };
    }]);
    var app = angular.module("app", ["app.configurations", "app.routes"]);
    app.requires[app.requires.length] = "ag.test";
    app.run(["agTestFactory", function(tf) {
        tf.hello();
    }]);
})();
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, when you can take a look to this topic.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/w0ZEBz02l8s